# Oracle several counts over partition

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below query which is outputting the below results:

```
SELECT
    a,
    b,
    COUNT(1) count,
    round(RATIO_TO_REPORT(COUNT(1)) OVER() * 100, 2) perc
FROM
    t1
WHERE
    condition1
GROUP BY
    a,
    b
ORDER BY
    COUNT(1) DESC
```

| A | B | COUNT | PERC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Correct | Correct | 968272 | 89.37 |
| Mismatch | Correct | 52620 | 4.86 |
| Correct | NO VALUES | 44630 | 4.12 |
| Correct | Mismatch | 10722 | 0.99 |
| NO VALUES | NO VALUES | 6217 | 0.57 |
| Mismatch | Mismatch | 662 | 0.06 |
| NO VALUES | Mismatch | 294 | 0.03 |

How could I get the below enhancing the query?

| A | B | COUNT | PERC | COUNT_TOTAL_A | PERC_PARTITION_BY_A |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Correct | Correct | 968272 | 89.37 | 1023624 | 94.59 |
| Mismatch | Correct | 52620 | 4.86 | 53282 | 98.76 |
| Correct | NO VALUES | 44630 | 4.12 | 1023624 | 4.36 |
| Correct | Mismatch | 10722 | 0.99 | 1023624 | 1.05 |
| NO VALUES | NO VALUES | 6217 | 0.57 | 6511 | 95.48 |
| Mismatch | Mismatch | 662 | 0.06 | 53282 | 1.24 |
| NO VALUES | Mismatch | 294 | 0.03 | 6511 | 4.52 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are in *doubt* how to combine the aggregation with the *analytical function* on different levels, simple split it in separate CTE

The first CTE calulates the overall count and percentage, the second the same for the `A` column.

Then join both results to get the complete report.

```
with cnt as (
select a,b, count(*) count,
  round(RATIO_TO_REPORT(COUNT(1)) OVER() * 100, 2) perc
from  tab t1
where 1=1 /* some condition 1 */
group by a,b),
cnt_a as (
select a, count(*) count,
  round(RATIO_TO_REPORT(COUNT(1)) OVER() * 100, 2) perc
from  tab t1
where 1=1 /* some condition 1 */
group by a )
select 
  cnt.a, cnt.b, cnt.count, cnt.perc,
  cnt_a.count as count_by_a,
  cnt_a.perc as perc_by_a
from cnt 
join cnt_a on cnt.a = cnt_a.a
order by 3 desc;

A         B              COUNT       PERC COUNT_BY_A  PERC_BY_A
--------- --------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
Correct   Correct       968272      89,37    1023624      94,48
Mismatch  Correct        52620       4,86      53282       4,92
Correct   NO VALUES      44630       4,12    1023624      94,48
Correct   Mismatch       10722 ,99           1023624      94,48
NO VALUES NO VALUES       6217 ,57              6511        ,6        
Mismatch  Mismatch         662 ,06             53282       4,92
NO VALUES Mismatch         294 ,03              6511        ,6
```

I'm **not** claimint that there is a simpler solution with one pass, but *this solution* works.

Interesting is also why you in your sample data  expects e.g. for `Correct` three *different* values of `PERC_PARTITION_BY_A`

Comment: No, sorry, that was a mistake. I updated my original question with the actual expected percentages.

Comment: Well you have a total count of  `1.023.624` for `A = 'Correct'` and `1.083.417` rows in the table. This gives me a `94,48` - so I'm wondering where you get the three *different* `PERC_PARTITION_BY_A` of 94.59, 4.36 and 1.05 @JaviTorre

Comment: I'll go with your CTE solution as it seems there's no simple way to produce my expected output in just one statement.

Answer (score 1):

This answers the original version of the question.

If I understand correctly, you want the ratio of the value of `b` to the overall count.  If so, just calculate the ratio directly:

```
SELECT a, b, COUNT(1) as count,
       SUM(SUM(CASE WHEN b = 'Correct' THEN 1 ELSE ) END)) OVER () * 100.0 / COUNT(*) as perc
FROM t1
WHERE condition1
GROUP BY a, b
ORDER BY COUNT(1) DESC;
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain myself correctly. Please find the question updated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
WITH t AS
    (SELECT a, b, COUNT(1) AS cnt FROM T1 WHERE condition1 GROUP BY a, b)
SELECT DISTINCT
    a,
    b,
    SUM(cnt) OVER (PARTITION BY A, B) COUNT,
    ROUND(RATIO_TO_REPORT(cnt) OVER () * 100, 2) perc,
    SUM(cnt) OVER (PARTITION BY A),
    ROUND(RATIO_TO_REPORT(cnt) OVER(PARTITION BY A) * 100, 2) 
FROM t
ORDER BY 3 DESC
```

Comment: The second over_partition is working fine, but the COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY A) is not giving the expected results but the count after the grouping.

Comment: ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
00937. 00000 -  "not a single-group group function"